# How to revert GZIP compression?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have added few lines in `.htaccess` file to compress files and to boost website speed.

But after that, some javascripts are not working properly. so I deleted these lines from `.htaccess` file....

Till problem with these javascripts is there....

How to revert the condition ?

code added in and later removed from `.htaccess` :

```
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: Define "not working properly" please. What's working and what isn't?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Not working properly means few javascripts almost stopped working, few are working partially or few are working strangly... e.g. javascript for tab working partially...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RemoveOutputFilter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#removeoutputfilter) directive.

```
RemoveOutputFilter text/plain
RemoveOutputFilter text/html
RemoveOutputFilter text/xml
RemoveOutputFilter text/css
RemoveOutputFilter application/xml
RemoveOutputFilter application/xhtml+xml
RemoveOutputFilter application/rss+xml
RemoveOutputFilter application/javascript
RemoveOutputFilter application/x-javascript
```